# Ruby loop as variable or uri increment

Tags: ruby, loops

Here my query:

I am having a url example:
http://www.abcde.com/dir/go.php?id=1

I am using "open-uri" for URI.parse and URI.escape for requests..

I wanted to iterate the url something, like:

```
http://www.abcde.com/dir/go.php?id=1,2
http://www.abcde.com/dir/go.php?id=1,2,3
http://www.abcde.com/dir/go.php?id=1,2,3,4
http://www.abcde.com/dir/go.php?id=1,2,3,4,5
```

etc..
Sorry for my english, trying it from past 3 hours..

```
require 'open-uri'
tgt = "http://www.abce.com/dir/go.php?id=1' ORDER BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7#"

response = URI.parse(URI.escape(#{tgt})).read
puts response
```

As you could see, I already knew I am going to get different error on id = ORDER BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7"

but, I want to iterate the paramater id = 1' ORDER BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ..... so onn..
I am confused how to increment the values?

Got it.

```
require 'open-uri'
#require 'regexp'

trg = "http://www.abcde.com/dir/go.php?id=1' GROUP BY "
(1..10).each do |i|
uri = "#{trg} " +(1..i).to_a.join(",")
s = "#{uri}#"
res = URI.parse(URI.escape("#{s}")).read
puts res
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to read id=1 then id=1,2 and so onn

Comment: We need clarification about what you want to do. If it's a question of code, please include an example of your code and we can help you with it. If you haven't written code, then please understand that Stack Overflow isn't a "please write code for me" site.

Comment: Also questions without any implication of trying will most likely get ignored if not down voted and locked quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want.

```
(1..5).each do |i|
  puts "http://www.abcde.com/dir/go.php?id=" +(1..i).to_a.join(",") 
end
```

you will get:

```
http://www.abcde.com/dir/go.php?id=1
http://www.abcde.com/dir/go.php?id=1,2
http://www.abcde.com/dir/go.php?id=1,2,3
http://www.abcde.com/dir/go.php?id=1,2,3,4
http://www.abcde.com/dir/go.php?id=1,2,3,4,5
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a specific number of IDs for which you want to create a URL:

```
def url_with_ids(url, id_quantity)
  url << "?id=" << (1..id_quantity).to_a.join(",")
end
```

If you want to keep doing things with the same URL using more and more IDs, you can create a loop like this:

```
url = "http://www.abcde.com/dir/go.php"
n = 1

while true
  current_url = url_with_ids(url, n)
  # do stuff with current_url
  n += 1
end
```

EDIT: Ideally, you would use a real condition instead of `while true`, so that you break out of the loop once you've accomplished your goal.